# DragonRise USB gamepad not working

Tags: 10.10, gamepad, games

I have a [Gamepad](http://www.geekalerts.com/u/usb-gamepad.jpg) which is not working, I say "not working" because I was playing Urban Terror and the game was not responding to the gamepad button presses. How do I get the gamepad to work?

I tried it in some other games Torcs, SuperTuxKark, Enemy Territory.... but, Same, there is no response to any of the gamepad button presses.

Here is the output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0079:0011 DragonRise Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

*003 on third line is my Gamepad.*

And here is the output from dmesg: http://paste.ubuntu.com/579704

Comment: Gurav could you post the output of lsusb terminal command while your controller is plugged in so we can identify the controller chipset

Comment: Included the 'lsusb' output. Sorry it took my long didn't get time.

Comment: Hi Gurav thanks for the data do you have joystick package installed?

Comment: you mean "sudo apt-get install" . I have already installed that but still no luck. Thanks for you response Allan.

Comment: Did you install xserver-xorg-input-joystick, aswell as joystick? If you remove the device, then plug it back in; run the command 'dmesg' At the bottom, you should see something like:
> [17179584.928000] input: DragonRise Inc. Generic USB Joystick as /class/input/input1
[17179584.928000] input: USB HID v1.10 Joystick [DragonRise Inc. Generic USB Joystick ] on usb-0000:00:03.3-2.1 Can you confirm please?

Comment: Looks like its now detected but working like a mouse. It scrolls up the screen, left/right click and other buttons are not working. So looks like its detected as a mouse. here is the output of `dmseg` http://paste.ubuntu.com/579704/  
Thanks.

Comment: @GauravButola You might want to disable mouse and keyboard events in xinput driver. [Detailed howto](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/119073).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your game supports generic gamepads, than its going to work with this one as well.

To calibrate your gamepad use this command:

`jscal -c DEVICE`

You have to replace DEVICE with the path to your device (e.g  /dev/input/js0 ).

To test your device use `jstest DEVICE`

To realy see on which path your device is use `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`

e.g H: Handlers=event6 js0  =  /dev/input/js0

Comment: All games supporting generic gamepad support _this_ gamepad. What blogger meant is probably the list of games he played that support gamepad in general.